# Replace specific values inside a cell without chaging other values in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas and have the following dataframe (df) with a column (mycol1).

```
     mycol1
-----------------
|ABC            | 
|CDE            |
|EFG            |
|3              |
|2, GHI         |
|IJK            |
|2,4 KLM        |
|MNO            |
|5              |
|1, 2, 3, OPQ   |
|7 QRS          |
|STU            |
|UWX            |
|7              |
|XYZ            |
-----------------
```

I have used the following code with .replace method but it replaces the whole cell string value and not only the numbers.:

```
df.mycol1.replace(to_replace=({'1':'anything','2':'Something',
'3':'Values here',
'4':'Homework','5':'my work',
'6':'Any values here',
'7':'More values'}))
```

I would like to replace the number codes in each cell with string values such that the string values will be concatenated with the existing string in the cells. For example,

```
     mycol1
-----------------
|ABC            
|CDE        
|EFG            
|Values here    
|Something, GHI 
|IJK            
|Something,Homework KLM
|MNO            
|my work              
|anything, Something, Values here, OPQ  
|More values QRS            
|STU            
|UWX            
|More values              
|XYZ            
-----------------
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uh, what's your expected output? Can you edit that into your question please?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I got what I wanted from the answer by jezrael.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you did. But that doesn't excuse you from at least writing a decent question. Please understand that Stack Overflow isn't _just_ for you. Provide a [mcve] and indicate what you tried and why it didn't work. That's the least you can do in exchange for the help you get here -- write a legible post.

Comment: Ok got it. I have now edited my original question so you can have a better understanding of the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Definitely helps. Thank you for taking the feedback to heart. I've retracted my downvote and upvoted your question. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by dictionary with numbers as strings with codes, for replace substrings add `regex=True`:

```
d = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d', '7':'e'}
df['mycol2'] = df['mycol1'].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)
          mycol1        mycol2
0            ABC           ABC
1            CDE           CDE
2            EFG           EFG
3         2, GHI        b, GHI
4            IJK           IJK
5        2,4 KLM       b,d KLM
6            MNO           MNO
7   1, 2, 3, OPQ  a, b, c, OPQ
8          7 QRS         e QRS
9            STU           STU
10           UWX           UWX
11           XYZ           XYZ
```