# Replacing partial text in cells in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

This is an extension of a question asked and solved earlier ([Replace specific values inside a cell without chaging other values in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457754/replace-specific-values-inside-a-cell-without-chaging-other-values-in-a-datafram))

I have a dataframe where different numeric codes are used in place of text strings and now I would like to replace those codes with text values. In the reference question (above link) it worked with the regex method before but now it is not working anymore and I am clueless if there are any changes made to the .replace method?

Example of my dataframe:

```
    col1
0   1,2,3
1   1,2
2   2-3
3   2, 3
```

The code lines that I wrote use a dictionary of values that needs to changed and then regex is set to be true.

I used the following code:

```py
d = {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c'}
df['col2'] = df['col1'].replace(d, regex=True)
```

The result I got is:

```
    col1    col2
0   1,2,3    a,2,3
1   1,2      a,2
2   2-3      b-3
3   2, 3     b, 3
```

Whereas, I was expecting:

```
    col1    col2
0   1,2,3    a,b,c
1   1,2      a,b
2   2-3      b-c
3   2, 3     b, c
```

Or alternatively:

```
    col1
0   a,b,c
1   a,b
2   b-c
3   b, c
```

Is there any changes to the .replace method in the last 1 year? or am I doing anything wrong here? Earlier the same code that I have written worked but not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some experimenting, I found that for each code (numbers) in my cells I need to have a regex replacement statement, such as:

```
df.replace({'col1': r'1'}, {'col1': 'a'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({'col1': r'2'}, {'col1': 'b'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({'col1': r'3'}, {'col1': 'c'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Which results in:

```
    col1
0   a,b,c
1   a,b
2   b-c
3   b, c
```

This is just a work around as it will overwrite the existing column but it works in my case as my main objective was to replace the codes with values.